# Not getting "Publisher" information for an Install Shield “.exe” file. While launching the Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, installshield

I have created a setup(exe) for my WPF application using Install Shield with Digital sign.

While installing or uninstalling this setup(exe) i am getting the "Publisher" information. but my problem is while launching the Application not getting "Publisher" information. It is showing as Unknown.

Comment: Did you get a certificate from a trusted certificate authority, or did you create a test certificate locally? The latter would show up as Unknown because it wouldn't be trusted by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

Your **setup.exe appears to be signed** - this is why you see the Publisher info when installing/uninstalling your package. However your **Application.exe is not signed**.
You should sign all applicable executables in your solution.

Please refer to the InstallShield manual or see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505985/how-to-add-a-digital-certificate-to-a-singleimage-install-shield-installation-pr) for more info on how to sign specific output files inside your InstallShield package.