# How to add code signing certificate to setup file using Installshield in visual studio 2012?

Tags: installshield, code-signing-certificate

Tool: Visual Studio 2012, InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition(to create Setup). 
 Application Type: Windows Form Application using C#.

I have Created one windows form Application. And also created it's setup using Install Shield in Visual Studio 2012.

Now I have one Code Signing Certificate and I want to add it in my Project Setup. How can I do It?

Or I have to go with ClickOnce instead of InstallShield?

Any Suggestion?

Comment: I have try to add Certificate from Prepare for Release -> Releases -> Single Image ->Signing. But it display errors like :   -1027: Failed signing 58CD.tmp   -1027: Failed Signing 597B.tmp  -1027:Failed signing certificate.msi   -1027: Failed signing setup.exe

Answer (score 2):

Unsure about InstallShield LE, but Professional and above have a tab called "Signing" under the Release view where you can set up your signing particulars.
See here: [Signing Tab in InstallShield Professional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKTGW.jpg)

FWIW, InstallShield just uses the signing tools that come from Microsoft such as `signtool.exe` to sign the build.

Edit: Also found [this help doc from InstallShield](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ERRDOC/Build-Error-1027).

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio open your InstallShield LE setup project. 
Under **Step 6 "Prepare for Release"** double-click **Releases**. 
In the resulting window you are presented with the tree-view that contains the **Builds/Express/SingleImage**.
There is a tab named "**Signing**". Enter the path/filename for the Digital Certificate File, the Certificate Password, and specify which output files you want to sign. Install Shield then signs the installation program upon a build.

Got this info, and it worked for me, from this [answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21506695/1035778)